# Reboot Error during the installation of OS X Maverick

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, error, reboot

I have a Macbook pro late 2011, with Lion 10.7.5 and I was trying to update to Mavericks. After downloading it and the process of installation everything were fine, but during the reboot I get this error

[image: error]

And keeps rebooting over and over again, the only way I may access to used it is by recovery mode, and gaves me the error report (I'm not quite sure if I have to post it)

From what I've read is the Kernel, it is any update or something which I should download or where can I find it to fix the problem? I've also tried by the USB way but happens the same thing.

Note: I erase all my content to do the "clean install" so it has NOTHING on the hard drive which I've already check it

Hope you can find the solution because Im kinda scared, Thank you very much

PD:Excuse me for my bad english

Comment: Your English is just fine, but your computer is not. So reboot in Safe mode to see what happens then.

Comment: or reboot in repair mode cmd-r

Comment: I do, reboot holding shift. Its the only way I can use my mac, and appears the report of the error but not much more